# char \0 escape sequence - what does it mean?

Tags: c++, c

I'm reading this example

[The real "Hello World!" for CUDA!](http://computer-graphics.se/hello-world-for-cuda.html)
What does the `\0` in

```
char str[16] = "Hello \0\0\0\0\0\0";
```

stand for?

I'm not sure why the 16 char `str` has `"Hello "` inside it and then all zeroes then (this isn't a global variable). How can I be sure that it just contains zeroes?"

Comment: This is as good as `char str[16] = "Hello";`

Comment: @iammilind I'm quite sure it's worse. And the fact that it caused this question is proof of that.

Comment: "\0" represents NUL in ASCII, and it is used in C strings as the terminator of the string. For more informations try to look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string

Comment: You can't expect that everyone follows the link or reads it. You should mention that its about CUDA which is important in this case. With CUDA or GPU calculation in general it could be cheaper to pad with \0 instead of adding length logic.

Comment: The first two comments here completely missed why those NULs are there. Of course the same code would be generated if they weren't, but the fact that there are exactly six of them is significant and is an indicator of their purpose. The fact that the presence of \0 caused someone to ask what \0 means obviously does not "prove" that their presence makes the code worse.

Comment: @JimBalter Assuming for a second that you're right about the purpose of `\0\0\0\0\0\0`, the fact that so many of us "missed it", does "prove" to me that the code is bad, at least without a comment next to it explaining the purpose. Even with a twisted dislike of documented code, something like char `str[16] = "Hello 123456";` would be superior, if only to avoid any wild imagination involving `NUL`, `NULL` or quaint CUDA-isms.

Comment: This question should probably also be tagged CUDA, right? People seem to be missing the point.

Comment: @busy_wait Perhaps, but it really has nothing at all to do with the fact that it is CUDA.

Comment: @iammilind: You surely mean `char str[16] = "Hello ";` — mind the gap, err space.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`'\0'` is the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) `NUL` [*null character*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) (ASCII code zero).

There is no point in specifying all of the zero bytes in the array. The following are equivalent:

```
char str[16] = "Hello \0\0\0\0\0\0";
char str[16] = "Hello ";
```

> If an array is partially initialized, elements that are not initialized receive the value 0 of the appropriate type. <sup>[[IBM]](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Faryin.htm)</sup>

Since the length was given to be 16, the compiler will automatically ensure the rest of the array (after `"Hello "` is zeroed.) The author did this either to "be sure" the rest of the array was zero, or to serve as documentation for the reader.

Contrary to our initial analyses, the CUDA kernel is **not** "poking in bytes" to append `World!` to the existing string.  `Hello` is printed first. Then the kernel modifies the string to be `World!`, which is finally printed.

The only reason the string is specified to be 16 bytes, is because that is the block size the kernel is designed to work with, and they have to make sure that the kernel is not messing with memory it shouldn't be.

I've added some comments to the (partial) original code to make this all more clear:

```
__global__                              // The kernel which is run in parallel
void hello(char *a, int *b) 
{
    a[threadIdx.x] += b[threadIdx.x];
}

int main()
{
    // The line in question. There's really no point in padding it with zeros.
    // The zeros are *not* replaced, and only 12+1 bytes are being specified.
    char a[N] = "Hello \0\0\0\0\0\0";

    // These values are added (by the CUDA kernel) to the array above. Again,
    // since partial arrays are zero-filled, there's no point in filling this in.
    int b[N] = {15, 10, 6,  0, -11,  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    // 'H' + 15 = 'W'
    // 'e' + 10 = 'o'
    // 'l' + 6  = 'r'
    // 'l' + 0  = 'l'
    // 'o' - 11 = 'd'
    // ' ' + 1  = '!'

    char *ad;
    int *bd;
    const int csize = N*sizeof(char);
    const int isize = N*sizeof(int);

    printf("%s", a);                  // Print "Hello "

    cudaMalloc( (void**)&ad, csize ); 
    cudaMalloc( (void**)&bd, isize ); 
    cudaMemcpy( ad, a, csize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice ); 
    cudaMemcpy( bd, b, isize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice ); 

    dim3 dimBlock( blocksize, 1 );
    dim3 dimGrid( 1, 1 );
    hello<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(ad, bd);   // Add the values in b to a


    cudaMemcpy( a, ad, csize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost ); 
    cudaFree( ad );
    cudaFree( bd );

    printf("%s\n", a);               // print "World!"
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: @glglgl I approve of your edit. Had I realized it, I would have done the same :-)

Comment: [printf past a buffer] "print a bunch of garbage"... or crash.

Comment: I doubt that the author is trying to ensure anything ... those \0 are just placeholders for the bytes that will be replaced with "World!" ... they're a form of documentation. What they certainly aren't (contrary to some other answers and comments here) are string terminators.

Comment: @JimBalter Explain to me more about how they "certainly aren't ... string terminators".

Comment: Because, as I just said, they are placeholders that will be replaced with "World!". Not every NUL has the purpose of terminating a string.

Comment: "printf would ... either ... or ..." -- those aren't the only possibilities; the behavior is **undefined**.

Comment: @JimBalter your comments made me go back and take a look at the CUDA code. I've realized now it has nothing to do with null termination in this case.

Comment: Instead to `<del> old answer part </del>` , I feel you should remove that answer part.

Answer (score 6):

`\0` stands for `NUL`, Nul is used as a string termination character. Meaning it states the end of a string. The value of a NUL byte is `0x00`

Comment: No, it's `NUL` (as in the ASCII character) not `NULL` as in `(void *)0`.

Comment: @DevZer0 I wasn't going to downvote, but you're not getting the point. `'\0'` is the `NUL` ASCII character. `NULL` is a pointer, often defined as `(void*)0`. Yes, they're both zero, but they are differently typed values with different meanings.

Comment: That says it's the "null character", abbreviated `NUL` (as it appears in the ASCII table).  It says nothing about `NULL`.

Comment: @DevZer0 `NULL`, as the macro, can for example have value `(void*)0` in C, and `0L` in C++. You don't claim these to be a null byte, do you?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart so your saying NULL != NUL ?

Comment: @DevZer0 Then remove the EDIT at the end. It still makes no sense regarding this answer.

Comment: @DevZer0 in the same way that "a vector" isn't the same as `std::vector`. Same name, used for similar reasons, but to describe different things: ASCII defines a character value named `NUL` to be "the null character" with value 0. C++ defines `NULL` to be a constant with the value 0. Of course they're related, but they're not the same.

Comment: Thank You very much for very informative discussion, i've personally learnt a lot. Thank you.

Comment: The NULs in this case don't have anything to do with ending the string. It might be useful to actually read the comments in the code.

Answer (score 2):

As stated it has little sense. `\0` just places the character with code 0 there, but it happens anyway. The good use of this is where array bounds are not given, as the extra 0 will count in, or where you have more characters after the 0.

```
char foo_and_bar[] = "Foo\0Bar";
```

will separate the parts with 0.

Comment: As stated it has plenty of sense. Those six \0 are placeholders marking the bytes that will be replaced by "World!". They aren't necessary, but they are meant to make the code clearer.

Comment: @JimBalter Just pointing out that the zero bytes are not replaced with "World!".

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Yes, I misunderstood the code; thanks for the clarity of your answer above.